# Is there a verb for when using all available space when packing?

Tags: verbs

What is the word for when you are packing and are you are using all available space, every nook and crabby?

Comment: Not *crabby* but *cranny*.

Comment: What "available space" are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

***[To cram](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cram)***:

> If you cram things or people into a container or place, you put them into it, although there is hardly enough room for them.
>
> - *I crammed my bag full of swimsuits and T-shirts and caught the sleeper down to Beziers.*

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

The word *jam-pack* might fit:

> to pack tightly or to excess

(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jam-pack))

It is a bit stronger than *jam* which already means

> squeeze or pack tightly into a specified space

(source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jam))